# Computing minimal cut sets from Binary Decision Diagram modelled using Python package dd

Tags: python, binary-decision-diagram

**Question**: How to compute the minimal cut sets (MCS) from a Binary Decision Diagram modeled using the Python package [dd](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/)?

**Definition**:
In a nutshell, and based on the example below, a *MCS* is that set of minimal and unique occurrences that lead to an output 1.

**Example:**

Given the binary decision diagram in the picture:

[image]

There are just three MCSs:

1. {BE1 & BE2}
2. {BE1 & BE3 & BE4}
3. {BE1 & BE3 & BE5}

Notes:

- A cut set is {BE1 & BE2 & BE3 & BE4}, but it is not minimal, because it is composed by the first and second cut set.
- The cut sets are composed only of those nodes with output 1. Therefore, the MCS is {BE1 & BE3 & BE4} and not {BE1 & ¬BE2 & BE3 & BE4}.

For the BDD you can use the code below (based on [this publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160582/learning-binary-decision-diagrams-bdds-from-data-in-python/66200465?noredirect=1#comment117050548_66200465)):

```
from dd import autoref

bdd = autoref.BDD()
bdd.declare('BE1','BE2','BE3','BE4','BE5')
# These are the assignments to the input variables
# where the Boolean function is TRUE (the y).
# The assignments where the Boolean function is FALSE
# are not used in the disjunction below.
data = [{'BE1': True, 'BE3': True, 'BE5': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE3': True, 'BE4': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE3': True, 'BE4': True, 'BE5': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True, 'BE5': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True, 'BE4': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True, 'BE4': True, 'BE5': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True, 'BE3': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True, 'BE3': True, 'BE5': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True, 'BE3': True, 'BE4': True},
 {'BE1': True, 'BE2': True, 'BE3': True, 'BE4': True, 'BE5': True}]

u = bdd.false
for d in data:
    u |= bdd.cube(d)  # disjunction so far
bdd.dump('example.png', roots=[u])
```

The output should be something like this:

```
mcs = your_function(bbd)
print(mcs)
[['BE1','BE2'],['BE1','BE3','BE4'],['BE1','BE3','BE5']]
```